# Excel's month function outputs dates in dd-mm-yy but excel then reads dates in mm-dd-yy

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm working with an Excel file where I have some values in the format `YYYYMMDD`  (ie, `19970203`, or `February 3rd, 1997`). I needed to convert these values into a date format that Excel can read, which I did by using the following function for the column next to these values:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

This outputs dates in the form of `dd-mm-yy` (so `03-02-97`, in the previous example). Now I needed to organize the dates according to month, so I tried to use the `=month` function on these new values in the next column. The output comes in the form of `mm-01-00`.

In researching I found that this formatting has been resolved by many by simply reformatting the cells to only display the `mm` value of the date. Unfortunately, Excel now reads these `mm-01-00` values as `dd-mm-yy`, and so interestingly enough, it's been January for the last four years.

I managed a workaround for my purposes, by avoiding the month function and instead using the text function on the dates, but I still haven't figured out what was going wrong with using the month function. I did some reading but couldn't find any reported cases of similar problems. It should be noted that I am running Excel on a computer with American regional settings, but the date display is in `dd-mm-yy`. However I don't understand how this could have any relation to my Excel problem.

Comment: The cell that you want to format as `mm` is the cell in which you have the `DATE` function; **NOT** the cell in which you have the `MONTH` function.

Comment: oh right, I guess simply reformatting to `mm` in cell with the converted dates works, but for my purposes I wanted to have a column with the month and a column with the complete date. A work around for this would be to duplicate the columns, but I was curious as to why I was getting `mm-01-00` values from the month function. The answer below answered this quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. The cell's format displays the serial number as a date such as `03-02-97`.

January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and February 3, 1997 is serial number 35464 because it is 35,464 days after January 1, 1900. If you change the format of a cell that's displaying a date to General format instead, the cell will show the serial number.

Excel is showing the cell with the `=MONTH()` function as `02-01-00` because the cell is formatted as a date, and the date for serial number for 2 is January 2, 1900. `MONTH()` returned `2` for February 3, 1997.

Change the cell with `MONTH()` to display the cell as a number (e.g., General) and the cell will display `2`.

Comment: Aha! Makes sense. Thanks for your answer, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:
`=TEXT(B1,"mm")`
in B1 you have your formula `=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))`
With your method you can change the cell format of `=month()` to `General` instead of Date(short or Long)
The cell format changes the display to what you want to read

Comment: Yes, the `=TEXT(B1,"mm")` is how I worked around the problem initially. Thanks for the suggestion! The cell format of the column with =month() (column C, in this case) is the problem, as you pointed out